# One to many relationship with junction table using Entity Framework code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, one-to-many

I'm creating a database using EF6 code first, and am struggling to create a one-to-many relationship using a junction table.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

`Foo` entities can contain any number (0-n) of `Bar` entities, however `Bar` entities don't necessarily belong to a `Foo`. I may want a different type of entity to also contain one or more `Bar`, so it's important that `Bar` doesn't contain its parent's foreign key.

So the join table would be like so:

```
Name        | FooBar
------------|-------
Primary Key | BarID
Key         | FooID
```

So if we create the entities as follows:

```
public class Foo
{
  public long ID { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
  public long ID { get; set; }
}
```

And then configure them:

```
public class FooConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
  HasKey(p => p.ID);
  HasMany(p => p.Bars)
    .WithRequired()
    .Map(m => {
      m.ToTable("FooBar");
      m.MapKey("FooKey");
    });
}
```

But this results in the following exception being thrown:

`An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: The specified table 'FooBar' was not found in the model. Ensure that the table name has been correctly specified.`

Unfortunately I'm not sure what this means - do I need to create a seperate `FooBar` entity?

**How can I configure these entities so that the join table is correctly created?**

Thanks!

Comment: `the child entity belongs to many different parent entities` if a parent may have several child you are in a Many to Many relation, and afaik this his the only cas you need/have a junction table in EF

Comment: I should have been more clear - the child entity is used by many different entities, but this is specifically a one parent to many children relationship which I'm struggling to create.

Comment: You mean a child may or not have a single parent, but may be in (another) relation with many entity of type Parent ?

Comment: I've confused things by using the entity names 'Parent' and 'Child', sorry. Parents can have 0-n Children, Children have 1 Parent. I don't want the Parent's foreign key to be stored on the Children however, because other entities also have these Children.

I'll change the names of the entities in my original question to avoid tripping over the meaning of parent and child.

Comment: junction table should have at least 2 columns and used for ***many-many*** relationship only. So you need to treat the relationship here as ***many-many*** instead of ***one-many***. Try replacing `WithRequired` with `WithMany()` and map 2 keys for the junction table (instead of just 1 as you did).

Comment: Thanks for your help, this does result in a junction table being created as expected, however both foreign keys are set as primary keys. I can only guarantee the child ID will be unique in this table, should that matter at all?

Comment: Just searched myself and discovered that this is a composite primary key, so that's new. This should work fine, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to store the key of `foo` in your `bar` then you have to go for a many to many relationship. The way you will make it act like a one to many relationship is up to your implementation after, there is still a way to make sure `bar` has only one `foo` , but for EF6 to make the junction table, the only way to go is many to many relationship.

Comment: Thanks, configuring this as a many to many relationship does behave how I intended it to, and for my purposes it doesn't cause any immediate problems.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to resurrect this thread, but I wanted to share a utility I created to handle a WebApi that had many instances of this same kind of relationship. We have multiple business objects which each have relationships to EventHistory, Messages, Files, etc, and it was messy keeping track of all the FluentAPI functions. Here's what I came up with:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Maps a many-to-many relationship that can only be navigated from TSource to TTarget.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">Source type that can navigate to TTarget.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TTarget">Target type that has no direct link back to TSource.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="modelBuilder">An instance of DbModelBuilder</param>
    /// <param name="expr">Lambda expression specifying the navigation property for this relationship from TSource to TTarget.</param>
    /// <param name="leftKey">Optional argument to override the foreign key to TSource</param>
    /// <param name="rightKey">Optional argument to override the foreign key to TTarget</param>
    public static void MapDirectionalManyToMany<TSource, TTarget>(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder, Expression<Func<TSource, ICollection<TTarget>>> expr, string tableName = null, string leftKey = null, string rightKey = null)
        where TSource : class
        where TTarget : class {

        modelBuilder.Entity<TSource>()
            .HasMany(expr)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => {
                m.MapLeftKey(leftKey ?? typeof(TSource).Name + "Id");
                m.MapRightKey(rightKey ?? typeof(TTarget).Name + "Id");
                m.ToTable(tableName ?? typeof(TSource).Name + typeof(TTarget).Name);
            });

    }
```

And I apply the relationship like so:

```
ModelUtils.MapDirectionalManyToMany<MyResourceModel, SharedHistoryModel>(modelBuilder, x => x.History);
ModelUtils.MapDirectionalManyToMany<OtherResourceModel, SharedHistoryModel>(modelBuilder, x => x.History, "renamed_history");
```